# Perl - regex to replace apostrophe space character with apostrophe character

Tags: regex

For example replace

```
America 's with America's
Can' t with Can't
```

`$str =~s/' \w/'\w/g;` obviously does not work

Comment: and the screen format was not exactly right for America' s

Comment: This will get really tricky for "my pants' legs" and such when you want to keep the space after the apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

Content of test.pl:

```
$foo = "blah America 's blah Can' t blah";

$foo =~ s/(?<=\w) ?' ?(?=\w)/'/g;

print $foo, "\n";
```

Running "perl test.pl" emits

```
blah America's blah Can't blah
```

Note that this is pretty tightly aimed at the use case that you seem to be describing.  If you want slightly different behavior (e.g. allowing for more/different whitespace around the apostrophe), you can presumably make alterations from this starting point.

The things appearing in the regex are as follows (spaces are shown as underscores below, just for readability):

- (?<=\w) : A zero-width positive look-behind assertion on a single word-class character (\w)
- _? : zero or one space characters
- ' : one single-quote character
- _? : zero or one space characters
- (?=\w) : A zero-width positive look-ahead assertion on a single word-class character (\w)

Look-around assertions (look-ahead, look-behind, coming in "positive" and "negative" flavors) are interesting and useful things.  You can read more about them in [the "perlre" documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), under "Extended Patterns" / "Look-Around Assertions".

Comment: @Robert: Because there's no guarantee that the whitespace in question borders a word character.  The OP included \w in its (failed) regex, so I assumed that it was important to only match extraneous apostrophe-surrounding whitespace next to a word, i.e. contractions that somehow got a stray space char in them next to their apostrophe.  The regex you list here will nuke all contiguous whitespace that follows any single-quoted string.  Yeah, I know, I'm working off an assumption about this being for contractions, but it seemed in keeping with the OP.

Comment: Fair enough. I was just curious.

Comment: @Robert: It's all good.  Thanks for making me think it through enough to explain.  And I still bet someone will shortly point out a much better way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks!  mlibby's method is great.  I need to spend a bit of time figuring our exactly how it works but its perfect!

Comment: I added a brief part-by-part explanation of what's in the regex, to help people make sense of it.  Those look-around assertions add a whole bunch of characters that make things look more complex than they actually are.  There are really only about five parts to the regex.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to just detect for either `(\s'|'\s)`. This matches on either `\s'` or `'\s`.

You might want to consider adding a `+` modifier to the `\s` as well to match more than one in case someone has America  's with two or more spaces.

Comment: This does not catch a space before AND after an apostrophe. Not sure if this is something the OP needs, though.